# Ember Data Async Relationships Not Loading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So I have a route that has lists of users on it. When I you click on their avatar you go to their profile.  The problem I'm running into is when I pass the user through the `{{link-to}}` helper and the transition occurs the properties that were marked as async in model are never fetched.  I'm attempting to access the async properties in the template in the profile so this should cause a fetch.

Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: You'll need to include the models, json, and templates

Answer (score 1):

In your `afterModel` hook you should fetch the async relationships.

```
afterModel: (model, controller) ->
  model.get('some_async_relationship')
```